# C# - Webclient Post Data Issue

Tags: c#, post, webclient

Im try to extract data from a website with webclient but i dont know the exact parameters for the Post and i receive allways empty data.

[Website: Red Arrow is the action and on green its the data i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30AWO.png)

To see the Post parameters i use Google Ghrome Developer Tools and in the tab "Network" i look for the Post Request Header.

[Post Request - Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM0Md.png)

My C# code its this:

**OLD CODE - This not working with webclient**

```
string URI = "https://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultaVendaAnuncios.aspx";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "*/*");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
    //wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Connection, "keep-alive");
    //wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength, "18801");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "_pk_id.70.0919=b6cdc4d1ee3456d0.1456252054.2.1456255268.1456255085.;" + "ASP.NET_SessionId=zlth2slu3o05ek511w5jb4rt");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Host, "www.citius.mj.pt");
    wc.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.citius.mj.pt");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Referer, "https://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultaVendaAnuncios.aspx");
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
    wc.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax", "Delta=true");
    wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

    string parametro1 = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch";
    string parametro2 = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlTribunais=False";
    string parametro3 = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTribunais=- Todos os Tribunais -";
    string parametro4 = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblDias=todos";
    string parametro5 = "__EVENTTARGET=";
    string parametro6 = "__EVENTARGUMENT=";
    string parametro7 = "__LASTFOCUS=";
    string parametro8 = "__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTE2MDIzOTkyMDcPFg4eCFBhZ2VTaXplAgoeCFdyaXRlTG9naB4OU2VhcmNoQ3JpdGVyaWEyvwMAAQAAAP////8BAAAAAAAAAAwCAAAAS1RyaWJ1bmFpc05ldC5XZWJzaXRlLCBWZXJzaW9uPTIuNC4zLjAsIEN1bHR1cmU9bmV1dHJhbCwgUHVibGljS2V5VG9rZW49bnVsbAUBAAAAPVRyaWJ1bmFpc05ldC5XZWJzaXRlLkRBTC5TZXJ2aWNlcy5WZW5kYUFudW5jaW9zU2VhcmNoQ3JpdGVyaWEDAAAAC19pZFVuT3JnUmVmBV9kaWFzCV9leHRpbnRvcwMDA25TeXN0ZW0uTnVsbGFibGVgMVtbU3lzdGVtLkludDMyLCBtc2NvcmxpYiwgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODldXW5TeXN0ZW0uTnVsbGFibGVgMVtbU3lzdGVtLkludDMyLCBtc2NvcmxpYiwgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MTkzNGUwODldXQ5TeXN0ZW0uQm9vbGVhbgIAAAAKCggBAAseC1JlY29yZENvdW50AscJHgpQYWdlTnVtYmVyAgEeC0xhc3RMb3dlcklkZB4LTGFzdFVwcGVySWRkFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIFD2QWBAIBD2QWAmYPZBYEAgEPEGRkFgFmZAIDDxAPFggeFEFwcGVuZERhdGFCb3VuZEl0ZW1zZx4NRGF0YVRleHRGaWVsZAUETm9tZR4ORGF0YVZhbHVlRmllbGQFCklkVW5PcmdSZWYeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QQFb0BFi0gVG9kb3Mgb3MgVHJpYnVuYWlzIC0tQ29tYXJjYSBkYSBHdWFyZGEgLSBBbG1laWRhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNENvbWFyY2EgZGEgR3VhcmRhIC0gQ2Vsb3JpY28gQmVpcmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw5Q29tYXJjYSBkYSBHdWFyZGEgLSBGaWcuQ2FzdGVsbyBSb2RyaWdvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGEgR3VhcmRhIC0gR291dmVpYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRhIEd1YXJkYSAtIEd1YXJkYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRhIEd1YXJkYSAtIFBpbmhlbCAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCpDb21hcmNhIGRhIEd1YXJkYSAtIFNlaWEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwuQ29tYXJjYSBkYSBHdWFyZGEgLSBUcmFuY29zbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRhIEd1YXJkYSAtIFYuTi5Gb3ogQ8O0YSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRhIE1hZGVpcmEgLSBGdW5jaGFsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGEgTWFkZWlyYSAtIFBvbnRhIGRvIFNvbCAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRhIE1hZGVpcmEgLSBQb3J0byBTYW50byAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDFDb21hcmNhIGRhIE1hZGVpcmEgLSBTYW50YSBDcnV6IC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gw4FndWVkYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDhDb21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIEFsYmVyZ2FyaWEtYS1WZWxoYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIEFuYWRpYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIEFyb3VjYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIEF2ZWlybyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIENhc3RlbG8gZGUgUGFpdmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwtQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBBdmVpcm8gLSBFc3BpbmhvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsL0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gRXN0YXJyZWphIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gw41saGF2byAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIEF2ZWlybyAtIE1lYWxoYWRhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsN0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gT2xpdmVpcmEgQXplbcOpaXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBBdmVpcm8gLSBPbGl2ZWlyYSBCYWlycm8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwqQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBBdmVpcm8gLSBPdmFyIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gUy5Kb8OjbyBNYWRlaXJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gU3RhLk1hcmlhIEZlaXJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsK0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQXZlaXJvIC0gVmFnb3MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwxQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBBdmVpcm8gLSBWYWxlIENhbWJyYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIEJlamEgLSBBbG1vZMO0dmFyIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsKENvbWFyY2EgZGUgQmVqYSAtIEJlamEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwoQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCZWphIC0gQ3ViYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDVDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJlamEgLSBGZXJyZWlyYSBBbGVudGVqbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbClDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJlamEgLSBNb3VyYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCtDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJlamEgLSBPZGVtaXJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsK0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQmVqYSAtIE91cmlxdWUgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwpQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCZWphIC0gU2VycGEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwrQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCcmFnYSAtIEFtYXJlcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC1Db21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhIC0gQmFyY2Vsb3MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwqQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCcmFnYSAtIEJyYWdhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2EgLSBDYWJlY2VpcmFzIEJhc3RvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2EgLSBDZWxvcmljbyBCYXN0byAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhIC0gRXNwb3NlbmRlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsKUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2EgLSBGYWZlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsL0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2EgLSBHdWltYXLDo2VzIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2EgLSBQw7N2b2EgZGUgTGFuaG9zbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDNDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhIC0gVi5OLkZhbWFsaWPDo28gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwxQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCcmFnYSAtIFZpZWlyYSBNaW5obyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC9Db21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhIC0gVmlsYSBWZXJkZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhbsOnYSAtIEJyYWdhbsOnYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDpDb21hcmNhIGRlIEJyYWdhbsOnYSAtIE1hY2VkbyBDYXZhbGVpcm9zIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2Fuw6dhIC0gTWlyYW5kZWxhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2Fuw6dhIC0gTW9nYWRvdXJvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQnJhZ2Fuw6dhIC0gVG9ycmUgZGUgTW9uY29ydm8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwyQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBCcmFnYW7Dp2EgLSBWaWxhIEZsb3IgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw3Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBDYXN0ZWxvIEJyYW5jbyAtIEMuIEJyYW5jbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIENhc3RlbG8gQnJhbmNvIC0gQ292aWxow6MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBDYXN0ZWxvIEJyYW5jbyAtIEZ1bmTDo28gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw7Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBDYXN0ZWxvIEJyYW5jbyAtIElkYW5oYS1hLU5vdmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBDYXN0ZWxvIEJyYW5jbyAtIE9sZWlyb3MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw0Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBDYXN0ZWxvIEJyYW5jbyAtIFNlcnTDoyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIENvaW1icmEgLSBBcmdhbmlsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQ29pbWJyYSAtIENhbnRhbmhlZGUgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwuQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBDb2ltYnJhIC0gQ29pbWJyYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIENvaW1icmEgLSBDb25kZWl4YS1hLU5vdmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwzQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBDb2ltYnJhIC0gRmlndWVpcmEgRm96IC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQ29pbWJyYSAtIExvdXPDoyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDdDb21hcmNhIGRlIENvaW1icmEgLSBNb250ZW1vci1vLVZlbGhvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOENvbWFyY2EgZGUgQ29pbWJyYSAtIE9saXZlaXJhIEhvc3BpdGFsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsL0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgQ29pbWJyYSAtIFBlbmFjb3ZhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgQ29pbWJyYSAtIFTDoWJ1YSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIMOJdm9yYSAtIEVzdHJlbW96IC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLENvbWFyY2EgZGUgw4l2b3JhIC0gw4l2b3JhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgw4l2b3JhIC0gTW9udGVtb3Itby1Ob3ZvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgw4l2b3JhIC0gUmVkb25kbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDhDb21hcmNhIGRlIMOJdm9yYSAtIFJlZ3VlbmdvcyBNb25zYXJheiAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRlIMOJdm9yYSAtIFZpbGEgVmnDp29zYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC1Db21hcmNhIGRlIEZhcm8gLSBBbGJ1ZmVpcmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwoQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBGYXJvIC0gRmFybyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbClDb21hcmNhIGRlIEZhcm8gLSBMYWdvcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCpDb21hcmNhIGRlIEZhcm8gLSBMb3Vsw6kgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwqQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBGYXJvIC0gT2xow6NvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgRmFybyAtIFBvcnRpbcOjbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCpDb21hcmNhIGRlIEZhcm8gLSBTaWx2ZXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwqQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBGYXJvIC0gVGF2aXJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOENvbWFyY2EgZGUgRmFybyAtIFYuUmVhbCBTdG8uIEFudMOzbmlvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsL0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGVpcmlhIC0gQWxjb2Jhw6dhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGVpcmlhIC0gQ2FsZGFzIFJhaW5oYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIExlaXJpYSAtIEZpZ3VlaXLDsyBWaW5ob3MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwsQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBMZWlyaWEgLSBMZWlyaWEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw0Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBMZWlyaWEgLSBNYXJpbmhhIEdyYW5kZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC1Db21hcmNhIGRlIExlaXJpYSAtIE5hemFyw6kgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwtQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBMZWlyaWEgLSBQZW5pY2hlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLENvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGVpcmlhIC0gUG9tYmFsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGVpcmlhIC0gUG9ydG8gZGUgTcOzcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRlIExpc2JvYSAtIEFsbWFkYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIExpc2JvYSAtIEJhcnJlaXJvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLENvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIC0gTGlzYm9hIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsK0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIC0gTW9pdGEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwtQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBMaXNib2EgLSBNb250aWpvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLENvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIC0gU2VpeGFsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNENvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIE5vcnRlIC0gQWxlbnF1ZXIgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwyQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBMaXNib2EgTm9ydGUgLSBMb3VyZXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBMaXNib2EgTm9ydGUgLSBMb3VyaW5ow6MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw5Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBMaXNib2EgTm9ydGUgLSBUb3JyZXMgVmVkcmFzIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNENvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIE5vcnRlIC0gVi5GLlhpcmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwzQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBMaXNib2EgT2VzdGUgLSBBbWFkb3JhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIE9lc3RlIC0gQ2FzY2FpcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDFDb21hcmNhIGRlIExpc2JvYSBPZXN0ZSAtIE1hZnJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIE9lc3RlIC0gT2VpcmFzIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgTGlzYm9hIE9lc3RlIC0gU2ludHJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsL0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgUG9ydGFsZWdyZSAtIEVsdmFzIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsM0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgUG9ydGFsZWdyZSAtIEZyb250ZWlyYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIFBvcnRhbGVncmUgLSBQb250ZSBkZSBTb3IgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw0Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBQb3J0YWxlZ3JlIC0gUG9ydGFsZWdyZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDFDb21hcmNhIGRlIFNhbnRhcsOpbSAtIEFicmFudGVzIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgU2FudGFyw6ltIC0gQWxtZWlyaW0gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwyQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBCZW5hdmVudGUgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwwQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBDYXJ0YXhvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMENvbWFyY2EgZGUgU2FudGFyw6ltIC0gQ29ydWNoZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDZDb21hcmNhIGRlIFNhbnRhcsOpbSAtIEVudHJvbmNhbWVudG8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwvQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBPdXLDqW0gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwyQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBSaW8gTWFpb3IgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwyQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwuQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBUb21hciAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDVDb21hcmNhIGRlIFNhbnRhcsOpbSAtIFRvcnJlcyBOb3ZhcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDFDb21hcmNhIGRlIFNldMO6YmFsIC0gR3LDom5kb2xhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsN0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgU2V0w7piYWwgLSBTYW50aWFnbyBDYWPDqW0gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwwQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBTZXTDumJhbCAtIFNlc2ltYnJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsMENvbWFyY2EgZGUgU2V0w7piYWwgLSBTZXTDumJhbCAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbD5Db21hcmNhIGRlIFZpYW5hIGRvIENhc3RlbG8gLSBBcmNvcyBWYWxkZXZleiAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDdDb21hcmNhIGRlIFZpYW5hIGRvIENhc3RlbG8gLSBDYW1pbmhhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOENvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIE1lbGdhw6dvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOENvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIE1vbsOnw6NvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsPkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIFBvbnRlIGRhIEJhcmNhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsPUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIFBvbnRlIGRlIExpbWEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw8Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaWFuYSBkbyBDYXN0ZWxvIC0gVi5OLkNlcnZlaXJhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOENvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIFZhbGVuw6dhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsPUNvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlhbmEgZG8gQ2FzdGVsbyAtIFZpYW5hIENhc3RlbG8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwvQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaWxhIFJlYWwgLSBBbGlqw7MgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwvQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaWxhIFJlYWwgLSBDaGF2ZXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwzQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaWxhIFJlYWwgLSBNb250YWxlZ3JlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsN0NvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlsYSBSZWFsIC0gUGVzbyBkYSBSw6lndWEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw3Q29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaWxhIFJlYWwgLSBWLlBvdWNhIEFndWlhciAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRlIFZpbGEgUmVhbCAtIFZhbHBhw6dvcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRlIFZpbGEgUmVhbCAtIFZpbGEgUmVhbCAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC1Db21hcmNhIGRlIFZpc2V1IC0gQ2luZsOjZXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwrQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaXNldSAtIExhbWVnbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC5Db21hcmNhIGRlIFZpc2V1IC0gTWFuZ3VhbGRlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNkNvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlzZXUgLSBNb2ltZW50YSBkYSBCZWlyYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCpDb21hcmNhIGRlIFZpc2V1IC0gTmVsYXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwzQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaXNldSAtIFMuUGVkcm8gZG8gU3VsIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLENvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlzZXUgLSBTw6F0w6NvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsNENvbWFyY2EgZGUgVmlzZXUgLSBTdGEuIENvbWJhIETDo28gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwsQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaXNldSAtIFRvbmRlbGEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwqQ29tYXJjYSBkZSBWaXNldSAtIFZpc2V1IC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZG8gUG9ydG8gLSBHb25kb21hciAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbClDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIC0gTWFpYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC9Db21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIC0gTWF0b3NpbmhvcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCpDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIC0gUG9ydG8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkbyBQb3J0byAtIFDDs3ZvYSBkZSBWYXJ6aW0gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwwQ29tYXJjYSBkbyBQb3J0byAtIFNhbnRvIFRpcnNvIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZG8gUG9ydG8gLSBWLk4uR2FpYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbCxDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIC0gVmFsb25nbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIC0gVmlsYSBkbyBDb25kZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIEVzdGUgLSBBbWFyYW50ZSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDBDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIEVzdGUgLSBCYWnDo28gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw0Q29tYXJjYSBkbyBQb3J0byBFc3RlIC0gRmVsZ3VlaXJhcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDFDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIEVzdGUgLSBMb3VzYWRhIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsOUNvbWFyY2EgZG8gUG9ydG8gRXN0ZSAtIE1hcmNvIENhbmF2ZXNlcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDlDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIEVzdGUgLSBQYcOnb3MgRmVycmVpcmEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwxQ29tYXJjYSBkbyBQb3J0byBFc3RlIC0gUGFyZWRlcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDJDb21hcmNhIGRvIFBvcnRvIEVzdGUgLSBQZW5hZmllbCAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDpDb21hcmNhIGRvcyBBw6dvcmVzIC0gQW5ncmEgZG8gSGVyb8Otc21vIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsLUNvbWFyY2EgZG9zIEHDp29yZXMgLSBIb3J0YSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDVDb21hcmNhIGRvcyBBw6dvcmVzIC0gUG9udGEgRGVsZ2FkYSAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDlDb21hcmNhIGRvcyBBw6dvcmVzIC0gUHJhaWEgZGEgVml0w7NyaWEgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw2Q29tYXJjYSBkb3MgQcOnb3JlcyAtIFJpYmVpcmEgR3JhbmRlIC0gVW5pZGFkZSBDZW50cmFsN0NvbWFyY2EgZG9zIEHDp29yZXMgLSBTLlJvcXVlIGRvIFBpY28gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw3Q29tYXJjYSBkb3MgQcOnb3JlcyAtIFN0YS5DcnV6IEZsb3JlcyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbDlDb21hcmNhIGRvcyBBw6dvcmVzIC0gU3RhLkNydXogR3JhY2lvc2EgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwxQ29tYXJjYSBkb3MgQcOnb3JlcyAtIFYuRi5DYW1wbyAtIFVuaWRhZGUgQ2VudHJhbC1Db21hcmNhIGRvcyBBw6dvcmVzIC0gVmVsYXMgLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWw1Q29tYXJjYSBkb3MgQcOnb3JlcyAtIFZpbGEgZG8gUG9ydG8gLSBVbmlkYWRlIENlbnRyYWwsTGlzYm9hIC0gVHJpYnVuYWwgZGEgUHJvcHJpZWRhZGUgSW50ZWxlY3R1YWwlTGlzYm9hIC0gVHJpYnVuYWwgTWFyw610aW1vIGRlIExpc2JvYUBTYW50YXLDqW0gLSBUcmlidW5hbCBkYSBDb25jb3Jyw6puY2lhLCBSZWd1bGHDp8OjbyBlIFN1cGVydmlzw6NvFb0BFi0gVG9kb3Mgb3MgVHJpYnVuYWlzIC0HMjg3MDkwMwcyODcwOTA3BzI4NzA5MTEHMjg3MDkxNQcyODcwODk0BzI4NzA5MTkHMjg3MDkyMwcyODcwOTI4BzI4NzA5MzIHMjg3MTM3MwcyODcxMzk3BzI4NzE0MDEHMjg3MTQwNQcyODcwMzM1BzI4NzAzNTEHMjg3MDM1MgcyODcwMzUzBzI4NzAzMzQHMjg3MDM1NAcyODcwMzU1BzI4NzAzMzYHMjg3MDM1NgcyODcwMzU3BzI4NzAzMzcHMjg3MDMzOAcyODcwMzM5BzI4NzAzNDEHMjg3MDM0MAcyODcwMzU4BzI4NzAzNTkHMjg3MDM4MwcyODcwMzYwBzI4NzAzODQHMjg3MDM4NQcyODcwMzg2BzI4NzAzODcHMjg3MDM4OAcyODcwMzg5BzI4NzA2MDEHMjg3MDU1NgcyODcwNTA1BzI4NzA2MDcHMjg3MDYwNAcyODcwNjEwBzI4NzA2MTMHMjg3MDU1OQcyODcwNjE2BzI4NzA1NjIHMjg3MDYxOQcyODcwNjIyBzI4NzA2MjUHMjg3MDYzNAcyODcwNjM4BzI4NzA2NDMHMjg3MDY0NwcyODcwNjUxBzI4NzA2NjAHMjg3MDY3NQcyODcwNjgzBzI4NzA2ODkHMjg3MDY5MwcyODcwNjk3BzI4NzA3NDEHMjg3MDc0NQcyODcwNzAyBzI4NzA3NTAHMjg3MDczMgcyODcwNzU0BzI4NzA3NTkHMjg3MDc2MwcyODcwNzY3BzI4NzA3NzEHMjg3MDc5NgcyODcwNzc4BzI4NzA3OTAHMjg3MDgwMAcyODcwODA0BzI4NzA4MDgHMjg3MDg2NwcyODcwODEzBzI4NzA4NzMHMjg3MDgzMQcyODcwODQwBzI4NzA4NDcHMjg3MDg2MQcyODcwODc4BzI4NzA4ODIHMjg3MDk2NAcyODcwOTczBzI4NzA5OTMHMjg3MDkzNwcyODcwOTk3BzI4NzEwMDIHMjg3MTAwNgcyODcwOTgyBzI4NzEwMTAHMjg3MTE0MgcyODcxMTY1BzI4NzEwMTcHMjg3MTE5NQcyODcxMTkwBzI4NzExNzkHMjg3MTI2NgcyODcxMjAzBzI4NzEyNzEHMjg3MTI0MAcyODcxMjQ5BzI4NzEzMTkHMjg3MTMyOAcyODcxMzY3BzI4NzEzNTUHMjg3MTI3NQcyODcxNDIwBzI4NzE0MjYHMjg3MTQzMAcyODcxNDExBzI4NzE3MzUHMjg3MTc0MAcyODcxNzQ0BzI4NzE3NDkHMjg3MTc1MwcyODcxNzE5BzI4NzE3NTcHMjg3MTc2MgcyODcxNjk1BzI4NzE3MjYHMjg3MTc2NgcyODcxODEwBzI4NzE4MDMHMjg3MTgxNQcyODcxNzczBzI4NzE4NDIHMjg3MTg1MAcyODcxODU0BzI4NzE4NTgHMjg3MTg0NgcyODcxODYyBzI4NzE4NzIHMjg3MTg2NwcyODcxODIxBzI4NzE4OTcHMjg3MTg5MAcyODcxOTAxBzI4NzE5MDUHMjg3MTkxNAcyODcxOTEwBzI4NzE4NzYHMjg3MTk1MAcyODcxOTQzBzI4NzE5NTQHMjg3MTk1OAcyODcxOTYyBzI4NzE5NzAHMjg3MTk3NAcyODcxOTY2BzI4NzE5NzgHMjg3MTkxOQcyODcxNTA3BzI4NzE1MTgHMjg3MTUzNAcyODcxNDM3BzI4NzE1NTYHMjg3MTU3NwcyODcxNjA0BzI4NzE1OTUHMjg3MTU2NQcyODcxNjQ4BzI4NzE2ODAHMjg3MTY4NAcyODcxNjU2BzI4NzE2NjMHMjg3MTY5MAcyODcxNjcwBzI4NzE2MzIHMjg3MDMzMwcyODcwMzQyBzI4NzAzMzIHMjg3MDM0MwcyODcwMzQ0BzI4NzAzNDcHMjg3MDM0NgcyODcwMzQ1BzI4NzAzNTAHMjg3MDM0OAcyODcwMzQ5BzIyNDQzNTEDMjE1BzIyNDQzNjkUKwO9AWdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2RkAgQPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWcWAgIFDxYCHgRUZXh0BRYtIFRvZG9zIG9zIFRyaWJ1bmFpcyAtZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WCAUtY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRQYWdlcjEkYnRuRmlyc3RQYWdlBTBjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJFBhZ2VyMSRidG5QcmV2aW91c1BhZ2UFLGN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkUGFnZXIxJGJ0bk5leHRQYWdlBSxjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJFBhZ2VyMSRidG5MYXN0UGFnZQUtY3RsMDAkQ29udGVudFBsYWNlSG9sZGVyMSRQYWdlcjIkYnRuRmlyc3RQYWdlBTBjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJFBhZ2VyMiRidG5QcmV2aW91c1BhZ2UFLGN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkUGFnZXIyJGJ0bk5leHRQYWdlBSxjdGwwMCRDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIxJFBhZ2VyMiRidG5MYXN0UGFnZY2mvXz5G77Wd+kpkYhEaMESDsZjB0vCyTbpf4XfYMCO";
    string parametro9 = "__EVENTVALIDATION=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";
    string parametro10 = "__ASYNCPOST=true";
    string parametro11 = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch=Pesquisar";

    string parametros = parametro1 + "&" + parametro2 + "&" + parametro3 + "&" + parametro4 + "&" + parametro5 + "&" + parametro6 + "&" + parametro7 + "&" + parametro8 + "&" + parametro9 + "&" + parametro10 + "&" + parametro11;

    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, parametros);
}
```

What im doing wrong?

**WORKING CODE FROM SAKURA + MYCODE to jump the next page**

```
string URI = "https://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultaVendaAnuncios.aspx";

CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest h = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
h.CookieContainer = cc;
HttpWebResponse hr = (HttpWebResponse)h.GetResponse();
using (var s = hr.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var r = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string html = r.ReadToEnd();                        

        Match mVS = Regex.Match(html, "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);                        
        Match mEV = Regex.Match(html, "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch");
        //param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$upResultados|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$btnNextPage");                        
        param.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        param.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        param.Add("__LASTFOCUS", "");
        param.Add("__VIEWSTATE", mVS.Groups[1].Value);
        param.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", mEV.Groups[1].Value);
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlTribunais", "False");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTribunais", "- Todos os Tribunais -");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblDias", "todos");
        param.Add("__ASYNCPOST", "true");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch", "Pesquisar");

        string post = "";
        foreach (var i in param)
        {
            post += WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Value) + "&";
        }

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);                        

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Referer = URI;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36";
        request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.citius.mj.pt");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true");
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                        

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();                        

        int x = 1;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        Dictionary<string, string> param2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch");
        param2.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$upResultados|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Pager1$btnNextPage");
        param2.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        param2.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        param2.Add("__LASTFOCUS", "");
        param2.Add("__VIEWSTATE", mVS.Groups[1].Value);
        param2.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", mEV.Groups[1].Value);
        param2.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlTribunais", "False");
        param2.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTribunais", "- Todos os Tribunais -");
        param2.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblDias", "todos");
        param2.Add("__ASYNCPOST", "true");                        
        //param2.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch", "Pesquisar");

        string post2 = "";
        foreach (var i in param2)
        {
            post2 += WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Value) + "&";
        }

        var data2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post2);    

        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
        request2.CookieContainer = cc;
        request2.Referer = URI;
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36";
        request2.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.citius.mj.pt");
        request2.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request2.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true");
        request2.ContentLength = data2.Length;

        using (var stream2 = request2.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream2.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();

        var responseString2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();  

        int y = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This site need `cookie` but you dont send it.

Comment: Thanks for reply Sakura. I try with this: `wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "_pk_id.70.0919=b6cdc4d1ee3456d0.1456252054.2.1456255268.1456255085.;" + "ASP.NET_SessionId=zlth2slu3o05ek511w5jb4rt");` but it gave me a error page.

Comment: you have to check other headers also, many of site check if a HTTP request dont have `Referfer` header, it will not accept that request.

Comment: Tnks for helping Sakura. I try with all headers and the problem still persists. I upload the code in the top.

Comment: One reason it fail maybe: all above values only can use onetime. If it is, you first have to run URI first, get it cookies, then send back these cookie to the page. This techicque require you change from `WebClient` to `HttpWebRequest`, which let you have more control about what server get and send.

Comment: Sakura the only this its different is the ASP.NET SessionID. You can see by this two different cookies  `_pk_id.70.0919=b6cdc4d1ee3456d0.1456252054.2.1456255268.1456255085.; ASP.NET_SessionId=ggjlhvlv5qvukm1msseg52nt `
 `_pk_id.70.0919=b6cdc4d1ee3456d0.1456252054.2.1456255268.1456255085.;" + "ASP.NET_SessionId=zlth2slu3o05ek511w5jb4rt ` I can use the same aproach that you tell me after?

Comment: If this cookie is different then all other header you send is consider is invalid. Because other encode header is base on this cookie.

Comment: Sakura i upload the code above. Still not working im not sure what im doing wrong. I try catch the cookie and send the post with webclient too, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Sakura using Fiddler the request header its the same except the ASPnetSessionID on Cookie. I have response from the website but without any data. UpdatePanel doesnt show any information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you not encode the POST data when you send back to server. You can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode` to endode them.

Here is modify of your code:

**Note:** wrap second request functions in `using` like the first request I do for you:

```
string URI = "https://www.citius.mj.pt/Portal/consultas/ConsultaVendaAnuncios.aspx";

CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest h = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
h.CookieContainer = cc;
HttpWebResponse hr = (HttpWebResponse)h.GetResponse();
using (var s = hr.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var r = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string html = r.ReadToEnd();
        //Console.WriteLine(html);

        Match mVS = Regex.Match(html, "id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        //Console.WriteLine(mVS.Groups[1].Value);
        Match mEV = Regex.Match(html, "id=\"__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        Dictionary<string, string> param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ScriptManager1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch");
        param.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "");
        param.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        param.Add("__LASTFOCUS", "");
        param.Add("__VIEWSTATE", mVS.Groups[1].Value);
        param.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", mEV.Groups[1].Value);
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbtlTribunais", "False");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlTribunais", "- Todos os Tribunais -");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblDias", "todos");
        param.Add("__ASYNCPOST", "true");
        param.Add("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch", "Pesquisar");
        string post = "";
        foreach (var i in param) post += WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(i.Value) + "&";

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post);
        Console.WriteLine(data.Length);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Referer = URI;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36";
        request.Headers.Add("Origin", "https://www.citius.mj.pt");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        request.Headers.Add("X-MicrosoftAjax: Delta=true");
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job... You help me a lot. Tnks Sakura

Comment: Sakura can you take a look on my new edited code ("WORKING CODE FROM SAKURA + MYCODE to jump the next page"? I try to get next page data but its not working and im not sure what im doing wrong. I were all day looking for solution... Im going crazy.

Comment: In the second responseString2 the result on updatepanel its like that |0|hiddenField|__EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|__EVENTARGUMENT||0|hiddenField|__LASTFOCUS||15172|hiddenField|__VIEWSTATE|/wEPDwULLTE2MDIzOTkyMDcPFgIeCFBhZ2VTaXplAgoWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgUPZBYCAgEPZBYCZg9kFgQCAQ8QZGQWAWZkAgMPEA8...

Comment: @BMont that is another question. As current question answered you should ask as new question then comment here to tell me. And I'll happy to help.

Comment: I create another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669841/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-get-data-from-pager-control tnks for helping